# ToSIC_EAV_DataTimeline in 2sxc dnn module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

What is the purpose of the ToSIC_EAV_DataTimeline database table?

I see that the table uses the most of the space in my database, so I am interested if can be "flushed / cleared / ..." or must stay intact?

Comment: Also, how can be cleared? (if can be)

Comment: Is there any other possible optimization on database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the data history. So basically all items can be restored to a previous state, but currently the UI is missing (it was there in v7 but we haven't re-created it for v8). So killing the history is a safe thing to do, of course when the history-UI comes again, you won't be able to roll back an item.